# INSTALL HTS 2.3 for HTK 3.4.1 on Ubuntu 16.04 has error

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I want to install HTS 2.3 but when I try to make all I get this error

```
> (cd HTKLib && make HTKLib.a) \   || case "" in *k*) fail=yes;; *) exit
> 1;; esac; make[1]: Entering directory '/home/ahad/Desktop/htk/HTKLib'
> gcc  -Wall -Wno-switch -g -O2 -I. -DPHNALG   -c -o esignal.o esignal.c
> In file included from /usr/include/string.h:630:0,
>                  from esignal.h:34,
>                  from esignal.c:29: esignal.c: In function ‘ReadHeader’: esignal.c:974:29: error: ‘ARCH’ undeclared (first use in
> this function)
>     if (strcmp(architecture, ARCH) == 0)    /* native architecture */
>                              ^ esignal.c:974:29: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
> esignal.c: In function ‘WriteHeader’: esignal.c:1184:25: error: ‘ARCH’
> undeclared (first use in this function)
>           architecture = ARCH;
>                          ^ esignal.c: In function ‘GetLine’: esignal.c:1760:4: warning: ignoring return value of ‘fgets’, declared
> with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
>     fgets(buf, len+1, file);
>     ^ esignal.c: In function ‘GetLong’: esignal.c:1808:4: warning: ignoring return value of ‘fgets’, declared with attribute
> warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
>     fgets(buf, len+1, file);
>     ^ <builtin>: recipe for target 'esignal.o' failed make[1]: *** [esignal.o] Error 1 make[1]: Leaving directory
> '/home/ahad/Desktop/htk/HTKLib' Makefile:141: recipe for target
> 'HTKLib/HTKLib.a' failed make: *** [HTKLib/HTKLib.a] Error 1
```

what is the problem?

I installed libx11-dev already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for resolve this two Error I specify the ARCH in ./configure like this:

```
./configure CFLAGS="-DARCH=linux"
```

its worked for me.

I do this step by step like this as Knud Larsen instruction:

```
   % tar -zxvf HTK-3.4.1.tar.gz
   % tar -zxvf HDecode-3.4.1.tar.gz

   % cd htk
   % patch -p1 -d . < HTS-2.3_for_HTK-3.4.1.patch
   % sudo apt-get install g++-4.7
   % export CC=gcc-4.7 CXX=g++-4.7 
   % ./configure CFLAGS="-DARCH=linux" 
   % make all
   % make hlmtools install-hlmtools
   % make hdecode install-hdecode
   % sudo make install
```

Answer (score 1):

---

Ubuntu 16.04 and the year 2014 code HTK-3.4.1, etc. :

The HTS2.3 patched HTK-3.4.1 ( HTKLib/ ) cannot be compiled with the default gcc = gcc-5.

Solution : `sudo apt-get install g++-4.7`

```
cd htk/
export CC=gcc-4.7 CXX=g++-4.7 
./configure
make all
```

---

Comment: make[1]: Entering directory '/home/ahad/Desktop/htk/HTKLib'
gcc-4.7  -Wall -Wno-switch -g -O2 -I. -DPHNALG   -c -o esignal.o esignal.c
esignal.c: In function ‘ReadHeader’:
esignal.c:974:8: error: ‘ARCH’ undeclared (first use in this function)
esignal.c:974:8: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
esignal.c:974:8: warning: left-hand operand of comma expression has no effect [-Wunused-value]

Comment: esignal.c: In function ‘WriteHeader’:
esignal.c:1184:25: error: ‘ARCH’ undeclared (first use in this function)
esignal.c: In function ‘GetLine’:
esignal.c:1760:9: warning: ignoring return value of ‘fgets’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
esignal.c: In function ‘GetLong’:
esignal.c:1808:9: warning: ignoring return value of ‘fgets’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
<builtin>: recipe for target 'esignal.o' failed

Comment: make[1]: *** [esignal.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/ahad/Desktop/htk/HTKLib'
Makefile:141: recipe for target 'HTKLib/HTKLib.a' failed
make: *** [HTKLib/HTKLib.a] Error 1